# spring boot adding = after data in post method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, post, spring-data-jpa

I have rest service,spring boot application, and a method to `POST` data, here is what it looks like :

```
@PostMapping("/data")
    Datum newDatum(@RequestBody String data) {
        return repository.save(new Datum(data));
    }
```

I using this request in terminal:

> curl -X POST "Content-Type: application/json" -d "abc" http://localhost:8080/data

Which returns me this:

```
{"dID":7,"data":"abc="}
```

Every time an extra **=**, that's the error, how can I solve this?

`Datum` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Datum {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long datumID;
    private String data;
    public Datum(){}
}
```

No to string method overridden.

**It also give me curl: (3) Port number ended with ' ' error, but data still gets saved**

Comment: Also include the code `Datum.java` class. I want to know what is inside that `toString()` method/

Comment: added, please check @ruhul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command worked for me, here

**`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "data_test" http://localhost:8080/data`**

Answer (score 0):

Your rest controller return Datum model which exist two attributes datumId or data or no parameterized constructor exist in your model. Then how to call a parameterized constructor in your rest controller? Next thing your response ({"dID":7,"data":"abc="}
) field not match with your return Datum model attributes. Please check once request is come in your application or other.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use single quotes in cURL
2. If you want to send an `application/json`, then send a properly formated JSON.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data": "abc"}' http://localhost:8080/data
```

Comment: here is the error :
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 4

and what i got in return :
```
{
  "datumID" : 97,
  "data" : "%27%7Bdata%3A=",
  "time" : "2019-11-02T05:00:58.603+0000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data": "aaa"}' http://localhost:8080/data

Comment: here is the error :
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 4

and what i got in return :
```
{
  "datumID" : 97,
  "data" : "%27%7Bdata%3A=",
  "time" : "2019-11-02T05:00:58.603+0000"
}
```